# Is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 more secure than TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384 in OpenVPN?

Tags: openvpn

I am reading the documentation about the configuration of OpenVPN 2.6.6 and I have a doubt about the TLS ciphers.

I run this command:

```
openvpn --show-tls
```

And I see the following Information:

```
Available TLS Ciphers, listed in order of preference:

For TLS 1.3 and newer (--tls-ciphersuites):

TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

For TLS 1.2 and older (--tls-cipher):

TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384
```

It is listed for version of TLS. I would like to use TLS 1.3 so it seems it is seem the recommended option is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, because it is listed in order of preference.

If I am not wrong, elliptic cipher is more safe than not elliptic cipher, but it TLS 1.3 it is not recommended any elliptic cipher, just AES.

So my question is, could I use elliptic cipher with TLS 1.3? Why doesn't it recommend an elliptic cipher for TLS 1.3?

I asked this because later, for another options, like tls cert profile, to use the profile suiteb, that it seems the most secure, it is only compatible with SHA256/SHA384, ECDSA with P-256 or P-384.

So in general, is it elliptic cipher better than don't use it? Why OpenVPN doesn't recommend it for TLS 1.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is, could I use elliptic cipher with TLS 1.3? Why doesn't it recommend an elliptic cipher for TLS 1.3?

ECDHE is the *only* option in TLSv1.3. That was part of the major changes in the new version; FFDHE was removed, as was any form of static DH or static RSA key exchange.

The reason you have a whole separate list for v1.3 is because ciphersuite **naming** has changed as well – among other things, the key exchange algorithm is no longer mentioned because there's only one option, *not* because it no longer exists at all.

(ECDHE is not a cipher, it's a key exchange algorithm.)

The certificate type was similarly removed from the ciphersuite naming because certificates have no influence over ephemeral DH anyway – so with ECDHE being the only option, there's no point in having separate ciphersuites depending on whether you have an RSA certificate or an ECDSA one.

Comment: Then, if TLSv1.3 use always ECDHE, could I set a curve with the option ecdh-curve?

Comment: Yes, but do you really need to? Since ECDHE is the only option, the OpenSSL library already has a default choice which is likely as good as any. It's not like in TLSv1.2 or older where you had to choose EC curves and DH parameters manually.